# setting up friendly url's for multiple domains in .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

For one domain I would use this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example-domain-please-change\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I don't know how to modify it, to be working with .com and .eu .I  don't want them to point to a specific folders. I just want to get rid of "www" in front, so they all point to the site's root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cond must match to pick up the % variables so how about:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.(.*)           [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*           http://%1/$0         [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect any `www.somedomain` to `somedomain`.

Comment: I've tried it on my test VM which mirrors my shared hosting service and it works fine for me.  Can you post your full `.htaccess`.  Also dump a hello_world.txt into your root and try that.